# Yii2 login connection Reset

Tags: php, database, yii2

getting this Error :

> yii\db\Query and yii\db\QueryTrait define the same property ($where)
>   in the composition of yii\db\Query. This might be incompatible, to
>   improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits
>   instead. Class was composed

Please help

Comment: file path :
 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php
 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryTrait.php

Comment: hey @user2742643, it will be good if you can post which code causing this error generation will be probably in one of your model file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

in `framework/db/Query.php`

```
remove lines 69 to 74

* @var string|array query condition. This refers to the WHERE clause in a SQL statement.
* For example, age > 31 AND team = 1.
* @see where()
*/
public $where;
/**
```

Comment: Yii2 is using .

/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php 
/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryTrait.php

Comment: check out this 

make a changes as per answer nd then try once ..


https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/9df21d46f364581076946e2b0156f1e18efd7c71

Comment: yii soft version used is 2.0.8


/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php   ==> not intialized variable like where,limit.



 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryTrait.php =>initailized varaibales like 

public $where;
 public $limit;
public $offset;

Comment: Ohh no.. Rollback changes i suggested... Issue is looking with your php version